# css body:after not working to stop on hover flicker

Tags: html, css, hover

I have icons for my socials in black and white with :hover pseudo selectors to change them to the full colour equivalents which caused the expected flickering, the code for these is as follows:

```
.header-main-socials {
  width: fit-content;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
.socials_icons {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#fb_icon { 
  background-image: url(../images/social-icons/facebook-bw.png);
}
#fb_icon:hover { 
  background-image: url(../images/social-icons/facebook.png);
}
#ig_icon { 
  background-image: url(../images/social-icons/instagram-bw.png);
}
#ig_icon:hover { 
  background-image: url(../images/social-icons/instagram.png);
}
```

I tried to stop the flickering using body:after and adding then hiding the content to preload however the flickering persists and if I remove the code to hide the content it still does not show up. Ctrl clicking on the url links takes me to the correct images and I am certain that the path is correct. I have tried with and without quotations within the url bracket with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
}
body:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  content: url(../images/social-icons/facebook.png) url(../images/social-icons/instagram.png);
}
```

EDIT: unsure if it is relevant for a task like this but I am using a reset style sheet, it's fairly long so I will provide a link to it's github instead of copy-pasting the entire thing: https://github.com/elad2412/the-new-css-reset

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>T</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/home.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header id="header-main">

        <div id="header-main-logo">
            <img src="images/trlogocustom.png" alt="TRLogo" id="logo_nav">
            <nav id="header-main-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" id="home_nav" class="active">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ourpeople.html" id="people_nav">Our People</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html" id="contact_nav">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html" id="about_nav">About Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        
        <div class="header-main-socials">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><div class="socials_icons" id="fb_icon"></div></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><div class="socials_icons" id="ig_icon"></div></a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <h1>home page</h1>
    </main>

    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body:after {}
```

Was being overriden by another css file called later in the html causing the content to be removed and the flickering to persist.

Answers by @mokorana are a good alternative to making separate images and getting around this if a later file needs the call.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you stick just to the colored images and use `filter: grayscale(1);`

As an example:

```
#fb_icon { 
    background-image: url(../images/social-icons/instagram-bw.png);
    filter: grayscale(1); 
}

#fb_icon:hover {
    filter: grayscale(0); 
}
```

EDIT

If you want to keep both images because they are different the following could help:

```
#fb_icon { 
  background-image: 
    url(../images/social-icons/facebook-bw.png),
    url(../images/social-icons/facebook.png);
  background-size:auto;
}

#fb_icon:hover { 
  background-size:0 0,auto;
}
```

Utilize multiple backgrounds to load both images and position the first one on top. Afterwards, modify  background-size  to display the other image upon hovering. By implementing this approach, both images will be loaded at the beginning and the second image will be prepared for display upon hovering.

---

Furthermore you might want to use only classes in CSS. So use icons named like `.icon-fb` instead of using ID-Selectors. But that's just a general tipp and has no impact at your question.

Comment: Hey thanks for the alternative, I didn't know that was possible so I will definitely use that for now but the colours are significantly different, do you have any idea what is wrong with what I'm doing? Also, why should I only use classes? I thought ids were for 1off elements and classes were for repeated ones, I'm still learning so I greatly appreciate you pointing that out I would have never thought to look something like that up

Comment: IDs shouldn't be used in selectors because these rules are too tightly coupled with the HTML and have no possibility of reuse. It's much preferred to use classes in selectors and then apply a class to an element in the page. I'll have a 2nd look at your code and update your answer if I have one. Can you update your questions with some HTML so that I have a real working example?

Comment: Thank you for the info, I have updated the question to have my html page in it

Comment: I tried to add your solution however for me both images disappear with this code

Comment: I just used [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/) to test the code with your HTML. Everything works fine. Check for yourself. Maybe the mistake is somewhere else in your code? Try to deactivate the CSS reset and other parts of your code to investigate further.

Comment: I'm not sure why I couldn't get yours to work maybe something to do with the styling of the containers I had those elements in, I did however find that a different stylesheet was using body::after and was overriding the one in the css above. Sorry to have wasted your time and I appreciate the tips you gave